# XAMPP server document root for specific website

Tags: apache, xampp, local, document-root

I just installed XAMPP, and I've found how to change the document root in the Apache config file, but I only want to change it for a specific site. The reason I need this is because all of my links are absolute links (i.e. /url not just url).

I tried changing it with .htaccess, but that gave me errors saying the limited recursion had been exceeded. So I went and changed that to 200, and it too a really long time, and then said that the recursion had been exceeded.

I would use aliases, but that would mean saying that any request to / goes somewhere else.

So is there anyway for me to specify that files inside of directory dir should have their document root as dir?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, but it's a bit involved. You have to change the Apace config file, and the hosts file.

In the Apache config file, I added this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "/absolute path/from/C/drive"
 ServerName site.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I had to add this in the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 site.local
```

You can read up more on the virtual host here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html